# rsync flag confusion around `-a`'s `-D` and `-g` falgs

Tags: rsync

It seems like `rsync` is commonly called using the flag `-a` which is equal to `-rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)`

```
    -g, --group                 preserve group
        --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
        --specials              preserve special files
    -D                          same as --devices --specials
```

What I'm confused about is why `-a` includes `-g` and `-D`. `-g` seems to do everything `-D` does, so why would you include `-D`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got that wrong. `-g` is equal to `--group`, it doesn't include `--devices` or `--specials`. The indentation is not meant to group features, read this more as a table with 3 columns with short switch, long switch and description where `--devices` and `--specials` don't have a short form.

Comment: Crap, I've been reading `man` files wrong for a while then...

Comment: @Tom: "Oops" :D